# Reading and Writing data in CSV files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and I am having some problems with CSV files in Python. Please help me out

1. How do I open and read csv files in Python which are present in some other directory? I know we can do

   ```
   import csv 
   f = open('attendees1.csv')
   ```

   As long as my program file and csv file is in the same directory. But how do I provide a link to the csv file sitting in another directory?
2. I have a list with multiple rows and columns, how do I transfer this data to a csv file and save it down in a particular location?

Please help me out

Comment: You can specify the whole path in the open statement. E.g.: f = open('C:\\mypath\\myfile.csv') or f = open('..\\other_path\\myfile.csv') if you are on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Kotlet, 
Can you help me with the 2nd query as well?

Comment: you can transfer your data with the csv.writer . Please see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: It would help to know the version of Python (2 vs. 3) and whether you need to handle non-ASCII input/output. The `csv` module is quirky, and requires the original file to be opened in different ways on Py2 vs. Py3. Use the `csv` docs appropriate to your Python version (kotlet gave the link for Py2, and the [Py3 `csv` docs are here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First argument of [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is file, which can be an absolute path like `C:\Program Files\file.csv` or a relative one like `../../file.csv` here `..` refers to the directory above the current directory and `.` refers to the current directory.

```
import csv
with open('../path/to/file.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerows(your_row_data)
```

Where `your_row_data` is a list of lists.